# Spherical coordinate: components of the electric field generated by a moving charge

Tags: mathematical-physics, coordinate-systems, polar-coordinates, spherical-coordinates, vector-fields

I have a vectorial function of the electric field $\overline E$ of a charge with velocity $\overline{v}$ (along the axis $x$).
This function $\overline E$ (or **E**), is shown in the following figure,

[image]

$$\overline E=\overline E_r(r, \vartheta,0)=k_e\,\dfrac q{r^2}\,\hat{\textbf r}\,\dfrac{1-\beta^2}{(1-\beta^2\,\sin^2\vartheta)^{3/2}}$$ with $\overline E_r(r, \vartheta,0)=\overline E_r(r, \vartheta,t)$ and $(t=0)$.
where $r=d(q,P)$ at $(t=0)$, with $r$ the distance between the charge and a point $P\in \mathbb{R}^3$, $\vartheta$ is the angle between the axis $x$ and $\overline{r}$ with $\overline{E}$ that have the same direction of  $\overline{r}$.

Considering the spherical coordinate (polar coordinate in the space), why the components of the electric field $\overline E$ are independent to azimuthal coordinate $\varphi$ (horizontal angle), $E_\varphi=0$, and of the colatitude $\vartheta$, $E_\vartheta=0$?

Comment: Something that is spherically symmetric has no dependence on the spherical angles, since this expression depends on $\vartheta$ it can't be spherically symmetric. Isotropy is a measure of Independence of angle, an isotropic field looks the same in every direction, this field is symmetric about the direction of travel

Comment: I would if I were on a laptop, best way is to compare it to a static charge which is radially symmetric